# Add html element left of centered content

Tags: html, position

My client want to have a 1000px width centered container with an ad banner to the left. The problem should be obvious. I struggle with centering the content and placing the ad banner at the same time. When the screen width is 1024px the banner shouldn't be visible. Is this possible? How?

Here's what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using this should allow you to hide the banner while the screen width is less than 1024px

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1024px) {
    .yourBannerClass { display:none; }
}
```

Concerning the banner position, why don't you use "position:absolute" to place it ?

Comment: `position: absolute` may not be desired because it positions the element relative to the its closest non-static positioned ancestor (in this case probably the browser's top-left corner). The OP may want to position the ads relative to the content container, which is currently not clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The center container's CSS should be like:

```
.center
    {
    width: 1000px;
    margin:auto;
    }
```

The ad banner should be absolutely positioned so that it does not affect the center container.

You can use Jquery to determine the screen width in pixels and then use it to change the style parameter for your ad box to `display:none;` if the screen width is 1024px.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to place the ad beside your container.

**Method 1:**

Assuming you know how wide the ad is going to be, you could do this with an extra container that wraps both your content container *and* ads. The extra container would have the width of the content container plus two times the width of an ad. This leaves you room to place ads on both the left and right sides of your content container.

**Method 2:**

Use `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` to position the ads. The problem with this is that resizing the width of the browser will not appropriately change the position of the ad *relative to your content container*. However, this is probably easier than method 1.

Regarding the issue with hiding the ads, you could use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it:

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.ad {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -125px;
    top: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1125px) {
    .ad {
        display: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    container content here
    <div class="ad">
        ad code here
    </div>  
</div>
```

This is assuming that you want a 100px wide ad with a 25px margin between it and the main content div.  Basically this just makes the `.container` div centered and `position: relative` and then positions the ad relative to the `.container` div.  The ad is hidden once the screen becomes too small (ad width + margin + 1000px).  You might also want to add `overflow: hidden;` on the `body` element to avoid horizontal scrollbars if the media query fails for whatever reason.

Absolutely positioned divs are positioned relative to the top left corner of their first parent element with `position: relative` (in this case the `.container` div) which is why the ad HTML is inside of the container.